# Synchronize output of two independent processes Python

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, synchronization, python-multiprocessing

I am developing a multiprocess code to compute in parallel some parameters in two parallel processes, then these parameters are used in the main process when available.

In particular I am working in the 3D audio field (developing a 3D audio simulator with audio obstacles), the above two processes compute the interpolated HRIR for the given sound source position and the cutoff frequency (obstacle simulation) for the given sound source and obstacle position.

The "structure" is the following:

[image: schema]

To make things clearer:

1. The main process spawns the 2 subprocesses and initializes them with a sequence of source and object positions to be simulated
2. The main process goes on with its own things (doing DSP stuff ecc...)
3. When the two subprocesses have completed their processing for a single position, they output the HRIR and cutoff. These two parameters are updated in the main process which will continue with its own DSP stuff, but using the two new parameters

This is my code so far:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from classes.convolutioner import Convolutioner
import librosa
from classes.HRIR_interpreter_min_phase_linear_interpolation import HRIR_interpreter_min_phase_linear_interpolation
from classes.object_renderer import ObjectRenderer
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue
#Useful video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sp7EhjLkFY4&t=17s&ab_channel=codebasics

def compute_hrir(queue_source_position,queue_computed_hrirs):
    print('computing hrir')
    SOFA_filename = '../HRTF_data/HUTUBS_min_phase.sofa'
    # loading the simulated dataset using the support class HRIRInterpreter
    HRIRInterpreter = HRIR_interpreter_min_phase_linear_interpolation(SOFA_filename=SOFA_filename)

    #Continua a runnare in eterno in attesa di nuove posizioni
    while(True):
        #print('inside while loop')
        time.sleep(1)
        #print('state of the queue', queue_source_position.empty())

        if(queue_source_position.empty() is False):
            position = queue_source_position.get()
            required_IR = HRIRInterpreter.get_interpolated_IR(position[0], position[1], 1)
            queue_computed_hrirs.put(required_IR)
            #print('printing computed HRIR:', required_IR)

def compute_cutoff(queue_source_position, queue_object_position, queue_computed_cutoff):
    print('computing cutoff')
    cutoff = 20000
    object_renderer = ObjectRenderer()

    while(True):
        time.sleep(1)
        #print('status of source position queue:', queue_source_position.empty)
        if(queue_object_position.empty() is False):
            print('inside object position update')
            object_positions = queue_object_position.get()
            object_renderer.update_object_position(object_positions)

        if(queue_source_position.empty() is False):
            print('inside source position update')
            source_position = queue_source_position.get()
            cutoff = object_renderer.get_cutoff(azimuth=source_position[0], elevation=source_position[1])

        queue_computed_cutoff.put(cutoff)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = 0
    source_position = np.zeros(2)
    current_cutoff = 0
    object_positions = np.array([(20, 0), (40, 0), (180, 0), (225, 0)])

    queue_source_position_hrir_calculator = Queue()
    queue_source_position_cutoff_calculator = Queue()
    queue_object_position = Queue()

    queue_computed_hrirs = Queue()
    queue_computed_cutoff = Queue()

    while (i < 100):
        # print('into main while-> source_position:', source_position[0])
        queue_source_position_hrir_calculator.put(source_position)
        queue_source_position_cutoff_calculator.put(source_position)

        queue_object_position.put(object_positions)

        source_position[0] = source_position[0] + 10
        i = i + 1

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=compute_hrir, args = (queue_source_position_hrir_calculator,queue_computed_hrirs))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=compute_cutoff, args=(queue_source_position_cutoff_calculator, queue_object_position, queue_computed_cutoff))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    while(True):

        if(queue_computed_hrirs is not False):
            current_hrir = queue_computed_hrirs.get()
            print('current_hrir:')

        if(queue_computed_cutoff is not False):
            current_cutoff = queue_computed_cutoff.get()
            print('current cutoff:', current_cutoff)

        print('doing stuff with the new values of current_hrir and current_cutoff')

        time.sleep(1)
```

The two subprocesses create two different objects that encapsulate all the logic I need for my computation (the code of the objects has been removed for the sake of clarity of my question, it has been tested and in monoprocessing it works perfectly).

I would like the `compute_hrir(...)` and `compute_cutoff(...)` functions to happen in parallel, with their outputs synchronized, while my main process keeps going on with its things and uses the two new parameters whenever they are available.

**To make things clearer here it is an example:**

1. I have a sequence of source positions (expressed in degrees) that mimic the circular movement of a sound source around my head, suppose a vector like `[0°, 10°, 20°, 30°, 50°, 60°]`
2. I have a vector of obstacles (always expressed in degrees around my head), suppose `[10°,30°]`
3. My `compute_hrir(...)` function takes as input the source position vector (`[0°, 10°, 20°, 30°, 50°, 60°]`) and computes the HRIR for the various position at a given rate
4. My `compute_cutoff(...)` function takes as input the sources position vector and the object obstacle vector and outputs the computed cutoff
5. The two process runs in parallel, but their output must be synchronized: `compute_hrir(...)` outputs the HRIR for sound source at position 0° and `compute_cutoff(...)` outputs the cutoff for source position at 0° and obstacles at `[10°,30°]`. Then after a while,  `compute_hrir(...)` computes the HRIR for source position at 10° and `compute_cutoff(...)` outputs the cutoff for source position at 10° and obstacles at `[10°,30°]`, and so on...

How can I synchronized the output of the two subprocesses? At the moment my code runs independently and I get "unaligned" outputs (HRIR for position 0° but cutoff for position 20° as an example).

**NB:** I know that all the processes never end due to the `while(True)` condition. This is indended to run audio output until the user forces the simulation to stop.

Comment: First of all, `mulitprocessing.Queue.empty()` method is unreliable (see the docs). Your subprocesses will ultimately run out of messages on the input queues, but they never terminate while your main process will eventually run out out of output from the subprocesses, but it never terminates. So either something important is missing from the code (such as continuing to add new values to the input queues) or I am missing something. Also, the `queue_source_position` and `queue_object_position` queues are initialized with a different number of values and that is a bit confusing.

Comment: If your two subprocesses are constantly running and writing new values to their output queues, then the main process should simply be doing blocking `get` requests on each output queue: `while True: current_hrir = queue_computed_hrirs.get(); current_cutoff = queue_computed_cutoff.get(); print('doing stuff with the new values of current_hrir and current_cutoff')`

Comment: @Booboo ```queue_source_position``` and ```queue_object_position``` are two different things (if I understood correctly your doubt). The first one is an array of positions to be computed for a single sound source (audio). The second one is a fixed array of N elements with position of objects (obstacles). The first one refers to the audio played, the second one refers to the interfering obstacles, as an example a door between you and the audio has been played. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @Booboo I thought about that solution, but in that case my main process will be blocked until it receives new elements from the queues. My idea was to keep running the main process with the current parameters (```current_hrir``` and ```current_cutoff```) and when there are new parameters available from the 2 subprocesses, they are retreived and used in the main process.

Comment: But you can keep running and do whatever you want. You only block when you are through doing whatever you wanted to do and are ready for new parameters. Otherwise do you see your main process running doing "whatever you want" and then being interrupted automatically when new parameters are available? You can also start a thread that blocks on reading from the two queues to get the new parameters and do something with them.

Comment: @Booboo Could you please a little bit further? I don't think I uderstood perfectly what you mean. With the simple queue.get() my main process gets stuck until it receives something from the queue, am i right? Or it keeps going on even if it is empty?

Comment: You are right; `queue.get()` blocks if the queue is empty until there is something to get. But I am having trouble understanding how you see yourself continuing to run in your main process (doing what, for instance?) but when there is finally more input available you automatically know and stop whatever it was you were doing and get the new values and continue where you left off. None of that is made clear. So I can't see how everything fits together.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear! I have my two subprocesses that are initialized with an array of position and obstacles (written in the queues) by the main process. Then my main process actually starts its computation and (in my case) it start performing some DSP processing on chunks of audio using the HRIR and cutoff returner by the other 2 processes. It performs processing on a block of audio using the current_hrir and current_cutoff, then checks if new parameters have been computed by the other 2 subprocesses. If yes it updates current_hrir and current_cutoff with the new ones

Comment: If they have not been updated, it starts another processing another block of input audio with the old parameters. If the parameters have been changed by the two subprocesses, the main process uses these new parameters to process the audio chunk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236146/discussion-between-booboo-and-mattia-surricchio).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned `Queue.empty()` is unreliable; you need to use in your subprocesses blocking reads. To prevent looping forever, I have added code to place on queues an additional `None` value, which serves as a "end of messages" indicator. The subprocesses can test for this value and if it receives this special indicator it can either end up or if you want to continue to loop indefinitely, stop reading from the queue and just continue to use the last value read. I have included code to do both; the code to just return has been commented out.

The main process starts a thread that does the synchronization. It reads one message from each output queue and then writes the combined values as a single tuple to a new `threading.Queue` instance. The main process does a blocking get against that queue just to get the first value pairs. from that point on it does a non-blocking get using method `queue.Queue.get_nowait`, which will throw a `queue.Empty` exception if the queue is empty. *This is the only reliable way to test to see if a queue is empty.* But there is really no need to use this method in the subprocesses since the queue should never be empty until it gets that last "end of messages" indicator value.

I also made a few corrections. For example, there seems to be a race condition in the main process in its putting to the `queue_source_position_hrir_calculator` and `queue_source_position_cutoff_calculator` queues while modifying the values that it is putting. I think that's because it's a separate thread that is actually doing the putting and the loop is modifying the `source_position` value before the thread actually complete the put operation.

```py
import time
import numpy as np
from classes.convolutioner import Convolutioner
import librosa
from classes.HRIR_interpreter_min_phase_linear_interpolation import HRIR_interpreter_min_phase_linear_interpolation
from classes.object_renderer import ObjectRenderer
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue
import threading
import queue
#Useful video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sp7EhjLkFY4&t=17s&ab_channel=codebasics

def compute_hrir(queue_source_position,queue_computed_hrirs):
    print('computing hrir')
    SOFA_filename = '../HRTF_data/HUTUBS_min_phase.sofa'
    # loading the simulated dataset using the support class HRIRInterpreter
    HRIRInterpreter = HRIR_interpreter_min_phase_linear_interpolation(SOFA_filename=SOFA_filename)

    #Continua a runnare in eterno in attesa di nuove posizioni
    eof_source_position = False
    # Un-comment following line to return when no more messages
    #while not eof_source_position:
    while True:
        #print('inside while loop')
        time.sleep(1)
        #print('state of the queue', queue_source_position.empty())

        if not eof_source_position:
            position = queue_source_position.get()
            if position is None:
                eof_source_position = True #end of messages indicator
            else:
                required_IR = HRIRInterpreter.get_interpolated_IR(position[0], position[1], 1)
                queue_computed_hrirs.put(required_IR)
                #print('printing computed HRIR:', required_IR)

    queue_computed_hrirs.put(None) # end of messages indicator

def compute_cutoff(queue_source_position, queue_computed_cutoff):
    print('computing cutoff')
    cutoff = 20000
    object_renderer = ObjectRenderer()

    object_positions = np.array([(20, 0), (40, 0), (180, 0), (225, 0)])

    eof_source_position = False
    # Un-comment following line to return when no more messages
    #while not eof_source_position:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        object_renderer.update_object_position(object_positions)

        if not eof_source_position:
            print('inside source position update')
            source_position = queue_source_position.get()
            if source_position is None: #end of messages indicator
                eof_source_position = True
            else:
                cutoff = object_renderer.get_cutoff(azimuth=source_position[0], elevation=source_position[1])

        queue_computed_cutoff.put(cutoff)

    queue_computed_cutoff.put(None) # end of messages indicator

def process_output(queue_computed_hrirs, queue_computed_cutoff, output_queue):
    while True:
        current_hrir = queue_computed_hrirs.get()
        if current_hrir is None: # end of message indicator
            break
        #print('current_hrir:', current_hrir)
        current_cutoff = queue_computed_cutoff.get()
        #print('current cutoff:', current_cutoff)
        output_queue.put((current_hrir, current_cutoff))

    output_queue.put(None) # end of messages indicator
    

def process_block(current_hrir, current_cutoff):
    print('doing stuff with the new values of current_hrir and current_cutoff', current_hrir, current_cutoff)
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    current_cutoff = 0

    queue_source_position_hrir_calculator = Queue()
    queue_source_position_cutoff_calculator = Queue()

    queue_computed_hrirs = Queue()
    queue_computed_cutoff = Queue()

    i = 0.0
    for _ in range(100):
        # print('into main while-> source_position:', source_position[0])
        source_position = np.array([i, 0.0])
        queue_source_position_hrir_calculator.put(source_position)
        queue_source_position_cutoff_calculator.put(source_position)
        i += 10
    queue_source_position_hrir_calculator.put(None) # "end of messages" indicator
    queue_source_position_cutoff_calculator.put(None) # "end of messages" indicator

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=compute_hrir, args=(queue_source_position_hrir_calculator, queue_computed_hrirs))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=compute_cutoff, args=(queue_source_position_cutoff_calculator, queue_computed_cutoff))

    output_queue = queue.Queue()
    t = threading.Thread(target=process_output, args=(queue_computed_hrirs, queue_computed_cutoff, output_queue))

    t.start()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()


    # get first set of values:
    current_hrir, current_cutoff = output_queue.get()
    while True:
        process_block(current_hrir, current_cutoff)
        # any new values?
        try:
            tpl = output_queue.get_nowait()
            if tpl is None: # end of messages indicator
                break
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
        else:
            current_hrir, current_cutoff = tpl
        # don't sleep too long so you can keep up with rate queue is being filled
        time.sleep(.8)

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    t.join()
```

Comment: I didn't think at all about another thread to perform the synchronization, that's really smart! Could you please suggest me some useful resources for multiprocessing/multithreading in python, if you have any? I saw many tutorial and studying a couple of books, but they don't go further than very basic examples where the synchronization task is very very easy. Thank you

Comment: Go to [lpvcpp/learn_python](https://github.com/lpvcpp/learn_python) and download  *Python Cookbook, 3rd Edition*. There is lots of good stuff about Python in general and a chapter on concurrency. Unfortunately, I don't know of anything that goes in great depth about multiprocessing/multithreading. There are other books you can download that I have not looked at. By the way, upvoting is good (I assume it was you), but *accepting* the answer is better if this has resolved your problem.

Comment: Yes, i wanted to end the discussion before accepting :) Thank you again

Comment: You might want to look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68859980/how-to-get-concurrent-futures-processpoolexecutor-work-with-a-dictionary) as it deals with both multiprocessing and multithreading and ultimately uses a combination of both to get a more optimal solution. You might find it instructive.