# raise ValueError(err) - Implementation of multithreading using concurrent.future in Python

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have written a python code which scrape information from a website. I tried to apply multi-thread method in my code. Here's my code before applying multithreading: It run perfectly on my PC.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import investpy

def getCurrencyHistorical():
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    headers = {'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
               'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
               'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36 Edg/88.0.705.63',
               'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
               'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
               'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
    links = {"USD-IDR":"https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-idr-historical-data",
             "USD-JPY":"https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-jpy-historical-data",
             "USD-CNY":"https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-cny-historical-data"}
 
    column = []
    output = []
    for key, value in links.items():
        page = requests.get(value, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        table =soup.select('table')[0]
        #ColumnName
        rows = table.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            cols = row.find_all('th')
            cols = [item.text.strip() for item in cols]
            column.append(cols)
            outs = row.find_all('td')
            outs = [item.text.strip() for item in outs]
            outs.append(key) 
            output.append(outs)
        del output[0]
        #print(value)
        #print(output)
    column[0].append('Currency')
    df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns = column[0])
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Finished in {t2-t1} seconds')
    return(df)
```

But, when I convert to below, I got some error. here's the code after applying multithreading:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import concurrent.futures
from functools import partial
import psutil

def process_data(key, page):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    table =soup.select('table')[0]
    #ColumnName
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('th')
        cols = [item.text.strip() for item in cols]
        
        outs = row.find_all('td')
        outs = [item.text.strip() for item in outs]
        outs.append(key) 
        
    return cols, outs


def getCurrencyHistorical(session, pool_executor, item):
    key, value = item

    page = session.get(value)
    f = pool_executor.submit(process_data, key, page.content)
    return f.result()

def main():

    t1 = time.perf_counter()

    links = {"USD-IDR":"https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-idr-historical-data",
             "USD-JPY":"https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-jpy-historical-data",
             "USD-CNY":"https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-cny-historical-data"}


    with requests.Session() as session:
        user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.37"
        session.headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
        column = []
        output = []
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)) as pool_executor, \
        concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(links)) as executor:
            for return_value in executor.map(partial(getCurrencyHistorical, session, pool_executor), links.items()):
                cols, outs = return_value
                column.append(cols)
                output.append(outs)
            del output[0]
        column[0].append('Currency')
        df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns = column[0])

    t2 = time.perf_counter()

    print(f'Finished in {t2-t1} seconds')

    print(df)

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I got error `raise ValueError(err) from err. ValueError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 7 columns.` and it comes from the line `df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns = column[0])`. What is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Just a general comment: I know there are postings that claim that one should never do multiprocessing with a pool size greater than the number of *physical* cores you have when the tasks are purely CPU, as is the case here. But I have *not* found that to be the case. I can show a worker function that is 100% pure CPU and submit 8 instances of that function on a pool size of 8 (I have 8 logical processors and 4 physical processors) and it will complete in less time than had I specified a pool size of 4. In any case, you only have 3 URLs and so you should use `min(len(links), os.cpu_count())`.

Comment: I show 3 urls for example only @Booboo

Comment: I know that. I am saying that if you happened to have 4 physical processors you would be creating a pool size with one processor more than you needed and that would take more resources and time than necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`process_data` should be just like the non-multiprocessing case except for the fact it is only processing one key-value pair, but that's not what you have done. The main process now must do `extend` operations on the lists returned by `process_data`.

**Update**

You were not retrieving the data items for key "USD-JPY" because you were not looking at the correct table. You should be looking at the table with id 'curr_table'. I have also updated the multiprocessing pool size per my comment to your question.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import concurrent.futures
from functools import partial
from os import cpu_count

def process_data(key, page):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', {'id': 'curr_table'})
    #ColumnName
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    column = []
    output = []
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('th')
        cols = [item.text.strip() for item in cols]
        column.append(cols)
        outs = row.find_all('td')
        outs = [item.text.strip() for item in outs]
        outs.append(key)
        output.append(outs)
    del output[0]

    return column, output


def getCurrencyHistorical(session, pool_executor, item):
    key, value = item

    page = session.get(value)
    f = pool_executor.submit(process_data, key, page.content)
    return f.result()

def main():

    t1 = time.perf_counter()

    links = {"USD-IDR":"https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-idr-historical-data",
             "USD-JPY":"https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-jpy-historical-data",
             "USD-CNY":"https://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-cny-historical-data"}

    with requests.Session() as session:
        user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.37"

        session.headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
        column = []
        output = []
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(min(len(links), cpu_count())) as pool_executor, \
        concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(links)) as executor:
            for return_value in executor.map(partial(getCurrencyHistorical, session, pool_executor), links.items()):
                cols, outs = return_value
                column.extend(cols)
                output.extend(outs)
        column[0].append('Currency')
        df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns = column[0])

    t2 = time.perf_counter()

    print(f'Finished in {t2-t1} seconds')

    pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)
    print(df)

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
Finished in 2.1944901 seconds
            Date     Price      Open      High       Low Change % Currency
0   Aug 26, 2021  14,417.5  14,425.0  14,430.0  14,411.0    0.16%  USD-IDR
1   Aug 25, 2021  14,395.0  14,405.0  14,421.0  14,387.5    0.03%  USD-IDR
2   Aug 24, 2021  14,390.0  14,395.0  14,407.5  14,377.5   -0.14%  USD-IDR
3   Aug 23, 2021  14,410.0  14,435.0  14,438.5  14,404.0   -0.28%  USD-IDR
4   Aug 20, 2021  14,450.0  14,475.0  14,485.0  14,422.5    0.35%  USD-IDR
5   Aug 19, 2021  14,400.0  14,405.0  14,425.0  14,392.5    0.21%  USD-IDR
6   Aug 18, 2021  14,370.0  14,387.5  14,400.0  14,372.5    0.00%  USD-IDR
7   Aug 16, 2021  14,370.0  14,390.0  14,395.0  14,371.5   -0.10%  USD-IDR
8   Aug 13, 2021  14,385.0  14,382.5  14,395.0  14,366.0    0.03%  USD-IDR
9   Aug 12, 2021  14,380.0  14,395.0  14,407.5  14,366.0    0.00%  USD-IDR
10  Aug 10, 2021  14,380.0  14,375.0  14,402.0  14,375.0    0.14%  USD-IDR
11  Aug 09, 2021  14,360.0  14,370.0  14,387.5  14,357.5    0.07%  USD-IDR
12  Aug 06, 2021  14,350.0  14,360.0  14,377.5  14,347.5    0.07%  USD-IDR
13  Aug 05, 2021  14,340.0  14,330.0  14,360.0  14,321.0    0.21%  USD-IDR
14  Aug 04, 2021  14,310.0  14,325.0  14,347.5  14,304.5   -0.21%  USD-IDR
15  Aug 03, 2021  14,340.0  14,375.0  14,388.0  14,338.5   -0.55%  USD-IDR
16  Aug 02, 2021  14,420.0  14,465.0  14,472.5  14,422.5   -0.28%  USD-IDR
17  Jul 30, 2021  14,460.0  14,435.0  14,477.5  14,434.5   -0.14%  USD-IDR
18  Jul 29, 2021  14,480.0  14,490.0  14,502.5  14,482.5   -0.03%  USD-IDR
19  Jul 28, 2021  14,485.0  14,500.0  14,512.5  14,485.0   -0.03%  USD-IDR
20  Jul 27, 2021  14,490.0  14,473.5  14,497.5  14,465.0    0.07%  USD-IDR
21  Jul 26, 2021  14,480.0  14,510.0  14,522.5  14,470.0   -0.07%  USD-IDR
22  Aug 26, 2021    110.10    109.98    110.23    109.93    0.10%  USD-JPY
23  Aug 25, 2021    109.99    109.64    110.13    109.61    0.34%  USD-JPY
24  Aug 24, 2021    109.62    109.69    109.89    109.41   -0.05%  USD-JPY
25  Aug 23, 2021    109.68    109.81    110.15    109.65   -0.11%  USD-JPY
26  Aug 20, 2021    109.80    109.75    109.89    109.57    0.07%  USD-JPY
27  Aug 19, 2021    109.72    109.76    110.23    109.49   -0.02%  USD-JPY
28  Aug 18, 2021    109.74    109.57    110.07    109.47    0.16%  USD-JPY
29  Aug 17, 2021    109.57    109.22    109.66    109.12    0.31%  USD-JPY
30  Aug 16, 2021    109.23    109.71    109.76    109.11   -0.31%  USD-JPY
31  Aug 13, 2021    109.57    110.39    110.46    109.54   -0.73%  USD-JPY
32  Aug 12, 2021    110.38    110.42    110.55    110.31   -0.02%  USD-JPY
33  Aug 11, 2021    110.40    110.58    110.81    110.31   -0.14%  USD-JPY
34  Aug 10, 2021    110.56    110.29    110.60    110.28    0.25%  USD-JPY
35  Aug 09, 2021    110.28    110.26    110.36    110.02    0.03%  USD-JPY
36  Aug 06, 2021    110.25    109.77    110.36    109.69    0.46%  USD-JPY
37  Aug 05, 2021    109.74    109.49    109.79    109.40    0.25%  USD-JPY
38  Aug 04, 2021    109.47    109.07    109.68    108.72    0.39%  USD-JPY
39  Aug 03, 2021    109.04    109.32    109.36    108.88   -0.22%  USD-JPY
40  Aug 02, 2021    109.28    109.69    109.79    109.18   -0.38%  USD-JPY
41  Jul 30, 2021    109.70    109.49    109.83    109.36    0.22%  USD-JPY
42  Jul 29, 2021    109.46    109.91    109.96    109.42   -0.40%  USD-JPY
43  Jul 28, 2021    109.90    109.75    110.29    109.74    0.13%  USD-JPY
44  Jul 27, 2021    109.76    110.36    110.41    109.58   -0.53%  USD-JPY
45  Jul 26, 2021    110.34    110.57    110.59    110.11   -0.18%  USD-JPY
46  Aug 26, 2021    6.4815    6.4725    6.4866    6.4725    0.09%  USD-CNY
47  Aug 25, 2021    6.4756    6.4714    6.4811    6.4707    0.07%  USD-CNY
48  Aug 24, 2021    6.4710    6.4790    6.4851    6.4676   -0.15%  USD-CNY
49  Aug 23, 2021    6.4805    6.4915    6.4973    6.4788   -0.32%  USD-CNY
50  Aug 20, 2021    6.5012    6.4960    6.5057    6.4935    0.11%  USD-CNY
51  Aug 19, 2021    6.4942    6.4847    6.4997    6.4840    0.16%  USD-CNY
52  Aug 18, 2021    6.4841    6.4861    6.4872    6.4776   -0.02%  USD-CNY
53  Aug 17, 2021    6.4854    6.4787    6.4889    6.4759    0.17%  USD-CNY
54  Aug 16, 2021    6.4742    6.4774    6.4810    6.4719   -0.04%  USD-CNY
55  Aug 13, 2021    6.4768    6.4778    6.4854    6.4749   -0.02%  USD-CNY
56  Aug 12, 2021    6.4782    6.4767    6.4811    6.4719   -0.00%  USD-CNY
57  Aug 11, 2021    6.4783    6.4846    6.4894    6.4752   -0.11%  USD-CNY
58  Aug 10, 2021    6.4852    6.4826    6.4875    6.4774   -0.01%  USD-CNY
59  Aug 09, 2021    6.4857    6.4835    6.4895    6.4731    0.05%  USD-CNY
60  Aug 06, 2021    6.4825    6.4660    6.4848    6.4622    0.34%  USD-CNY
61  Aug 05, 2021    6.4608    6.4671    6.4677    6.4595   -0.07%  USD-CNY
62  Aug 04, 2021    6.4655    6.4662    6.4673    6.4555   -0.07%  USD-CNY
63  Aug 03, 2021    6.4700    6.4656    6.4710    6.4604    0.12%  USD-CNY
64  Aug 02, 2021    6.4620    6.4615    6.4693    6.4580    0.02%  USD-CNY
65  Jul 30, 2021    6.4609    6.4645    6.4693    6.4506    0.07%  USD-CNY
66  Jul 29, 2021    6.4562    6.4908    6.4908    6.4544   -0.53%  USD-CNY
67  Jul 28, 2021    6.4905    6.5095    6.5101    6.4891   -0.31%  USD-CNY
68  Jul 27, 2021    6.5104    6.4760    6.5132    6.4735    0.43%  USD-CNY
69  Jul 26, 2021    6.4825    6.4790    6.4875    6.4785    0.03%  USD-CNY
```

Comment: Thank you @Booboo for answering. Can u help to answer another problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68993281/how-to-get-concurrent-futures-processpoolexecutor-work